# Google drive API access

Tags: php-7, google-drive-realtime-api

This is a general question regarding Google drive API system.

I need to create a web app that shows only files hosted in Google drive.

What I've found on the web is mainly regarding authorizing API access to client's account. I need to set only ONE account that is the origin of my files.

How you could suggest to move into this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps the [`list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) function?

Comment: Yes. For me it's not clear how to list only my files and not files of the user visiting the website